# Compute value of element in structure tensor.

Tags: linear-algebra

As i know, Structure Tensor is:

$$M = \sum_{(x,y)\in\mathbf{W}}\begin{bmatrix}
I_x^2 & I_xI_y \\
I_xI_y & I_y^2 
 \end{bmatrix}$$

How i compute $I_x^2,I_y^2,I_xI_y$. I've used **Hadamard product** to compute $I_x^2,I_y^2,IxIy$. But if i use Hadamard product i will get det(M)=0. I'm stuck in here for too long. Can anyone explain for me?. Thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't give us enough information for us to help. In particular, we can't tell you how to compute $I_x^2$ unless you explain the form in which $I$ is given.

Comment: Also, have you tried looking at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor) about structure tensors?

Comment: I had looked wiki already, actually i try to build my own Harris Detection. I had compute $I_x, I_y$ which is gradient of $I$ followig x and y axis. I don't know how i compute $I_x^2, I_y^2, I_xI_y$